# Checking null value for integer from DataBase

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a student table that references a parent table, as a FK. But a student can be older than 18, in which case he's responsable for himself  and the `parent_id` is set to null. I have to check if the id is null, but:

```
if (dtreader_resp.Read())
            {
                if(dtreader_resp.GetInt16("resp_id") != null)
                {
                    resp.Resp_id = dtreader_resp.GetInt16("resp_id");
                }
            }
```

Always returns true. Is there a way to check if that field is null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [IsDBNull](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.isdbnull(v=vs.110).aspx) or use a nullable int:

```
var data = sqlReader["resp_id"] as int?;
if (data.HasValue)
{
    var actualValue = data.Value
}
```